# Vlc python library

Tags: python-3.x, vlc, subtitle

i am trying to make a media player that generates random subtitles based on nltk library. I am using the vlc python for it, for now i do not care about interface. But i have problem understanding how to put subtitles, even as a srt file.
The function is [SubtitleTrack()](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/) inside vlc.py. Somewhere else i saw that i must use the [add_slave()](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/vlc.MediaPlayer-class.html#add_slave) function.

My code until now is:

```
import vlc
Instance = vlc.Instance()
player = Instance.media_player_new()
Media = Instance.media_new('Test.avi')
Sub = player.add_slave(player,'Test.srt', True)

player.set_media(Media)
player.play()
```

The version of [libvlc is 2.2.6](http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=blob;f=generated/2.2/vlc.py;h=17b94eaa7928e8c9a85bb6578b6d8a153416c1ec;hb=HEAD)

Comment: What version of python-vlc are you running?

Comment: There is no version written somewhere. The only written is: Copyright (C) 2009-2012 the VideoLAN team and  __version__ = "N/A"
build_date  = "Fri Oct  7 12:04:48 2016"

Comment: Run this `pip show python-vlc`

Comment: It gives error.I haven't install it in python folder rather in project folder

Comment: Then go to your vlc.py file, and read the version there. `__version__`

Comment: There in no version inside, the text that i wrote in previous comments are from inside. I updated the question, with a new version of vlc.py. The pip still do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SubtitleTrack()` is a class.

What you want to do is add the subtitles after you hit play. How you do this, from my understanding depends on the version.

```
import vlc
Instance = vlc.Instance()
player = Instance.media_player_new()
Media = Instance.media_new('Test.avi')
player.set_media(Media)
player.play()
player.video_set_subtitle_file('Test.srt')
```

I don't have the `add_slave()` function on my local version of vlc, but I would assume it's safe to say functionality stayed the same for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vlc 2.2, you should use

```
player.video_set_subtitle_file('Test.srt')
```

but this method has been deprecated in the 3.0 release and you should use add_slave.

You can have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax it will help you with the URL concept, and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows/ for the application to Windows paths.

Comment: i will check both, i used  video_set_subtitle_file with 2.2, i will check with 3.0 because now i have a problem with the get_duration function